# Android ignoring font-size change via media query on HTML

Tags: android, css, webview

Basically, on a Nexus 7 when the font-size changes on the HTML element it's ignored. If I remove the smaller font size everything works as intended, but this adds it's own issues for phones.

CSS:

```
html { font-size: 10px; }

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-aspect-ratio: 21/15), (min-width: 768px) {
  html { font-size: 16px; }
}
```

It works if I remove the first line so the media query isn't the issue. Anyone have any ideas or come across this?

My only theory so far is it might be a bug with WebViews (this is currently in a web view).

Comment: have you validated the html?

Comment: Markup all passes. Whatever the issue it's going to be something more than that. Especially since this seems to be the only device I can replicate it on, but it does replicate every time.

Comment: why not try a media query for this and for everything else?

Comment: I'm using REM units throughout the rest of CSS. Makes things a lot easier to switch between phone sizing and desktop/tablet sizing.

Comment: I get the same bug in Chrome on Windows so I don't think this is WebView specific.

Comment: I think the fix I ended up with was setting `width=device-width` in the viewport meta. I had other stuff in there but there was a point where that was breaking things on older Android. Other changes solved that so putting it back seemed to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by adding an additional catch-all *@media* query and not specifying *font-size* outside of the *@media* queries.